# Why C++ allows repeated + operators, like in x = 1 + + + + + + + + 2;

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, grammar

To my surprise this [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/nMf5ob7hc):

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int x = 1 + + + + + + 2;
    static_assert(x==3);
}
```

I know C++ has weird complex grammar(and it tries to allow all C code to be valid), so I presume that is the case why this is allowed, but is there some good positive reason why we would not want this code banned?

edit: even more bizzare cases work:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int x = 1 + - - + + + 2;
    static_assert(x==3);
}
```

Comment: Why forbid it, is perhaps a better question (not the DVer)

Comment: @underscore_d at first I thought you are saying you are not:  David Vandevoorde :) As for downvote: I think question is fine, just not very useful, it is more of a language trivia, than a useful thing to know in everyday work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ it's possible to overload operators. Boost Spirit is a particularly good use case; using the C++ grammar to represent EBNF grammars.

In such contexts, it might be useful to be able to have repeated `+` operators.

(A personal example: I have some cash flow modelling code that uses `+` to advance by a period. Naturally `++` advances by two periods. I also use `<<` and `>>` to move cash between accounts. It's remarkably readable - if I might say so myself!)

Comment: See also [Multi-Dimensional Analog Literals](http://www.eelis.net/C++/analogliterals.xhtml)

Comment: Expanding (evil) MACRO might also produce similar code.

Comment: but aren't examples in my question *binary* + operators?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl only one is binary the rest are unary

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: The tokens are grouped `1 + (- (- (+ (+ (+ 2)))))`

Comment: Note that while the use in operator overloading may be an upside in allowing multiple unary operators, it is not the reason. C++ inherited its rules in that regard from C, which didn't have operator overloading. Plus, virtually every other language works the same way whether it has operator overloading or not.

Answer (score 4):

It's far easier for a grammar to define unary operators

```
*expression*: /* other things */
              *unary-expression*
              /* more things */

*unary-expression*: + *expression*
                    - *expression*
```

Than

```
*expression*: /* other things */
              *unary-expression*
              /* more things */

*non-unary-expression*: /* other things */
                        /* more things */

*unary-expression*: + *non-unary-expression*
                    - *non-unary-expression*
```

Your complaint is better solved with code-review, not grammar changes

Comment: Note that changing the grammar to disallow `+ + x` (which wouldn't be that complicated really) would still allow `+ (+ x)` and disallowing that would be a lot harder and probably not possible using an LR parser.